# My items and indentation are not rendering properly

Tags: r-markdown

I was trying to write some items with some code between them, like the example below

````r
    1. Line 1
    ```{r}
    (1+1)
    ```
        i) Item 1
    ```{r}
    (1+1)
    ```
        ii) Item 2
````

But when I ran this code, the items appear as if they were chunks results. Is something missing or is this a bug?

Comment: Have you tried adding some linebreaks between your blocks and your markdown?

Comment: @MaxTeflon Yes, one and two line breaks. They made no difference, so I remove them here to make the post shorter.

Comment: Did you indent your chunks like you did in the example?